# Compare Date arrays in loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'am trying to compare 2 date arrays(all_date, click_date) and set value 0 in array clicks if date not exist in array click_date

```
all_date=["2015-10-17", "2015-10-18","2015-10-19", "2015-10-20","2015-10-21","2015-10-22"]

click_date=["2015-10-17", "2015-10-19", "2015-10-20"]

clicks=[5,3,1]
```

Final result:

```
clicks=[5,0,3,1,0,0]
```

i used this code:

```
if(key==0){
  $.each(all_date, function( j, v ) {

      if(dateInitial==v){

        clicks[0].push(parseInt(val["nbrclick"]));
        return false;

      }else{

        clicks[0].push(0);

      }
  });   
  }else{

    for (i=0; i < key; i++){

      $.each(all_date, function( j, v ) {

        if(dateInitial==v){

          clicks[key].push(parseInt(val["nbrclick"]));
          return false;

        }else{

          clicks[key].push(0);

        }
      });
    }
}
```

but i get clicks array like this [5,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,0...]

what is missing in my code?

Comment: what does `dateInitial ` contain?

Comment: dateInitial contain first date from array click_date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply generate a new array using **[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** which generates a new array by applying a custom function to every item in an array.

For every item do the following:

- if such date exists in `click_date`, then get this index and find `clicks[index]`
- if such date does not exist - simply return 0

```js
var all_date=["2015-10-17", "2015-10-18","2015-10-19", "2015-10-20","2015-10-21","2015-10-22"];
var click_date=["2015-10-17", "2015-10-19", "2015-10-20"];
var clicks=[5,3,1];

var result = all_date.map(function(x) {
  var indexInClickDate = click_date.indexOf(x);
  return (indexInClickDate > -1) ? clicks[indexInClickDate] : 0;
});

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

Just to make it easier to understand, an algorithm above does *almost* the same as:

```js
var all_date=["2015-10-17", "2015-10-18","2015-10-19", "2015-10-20","2015-10-21","2015-10-22"];
var click_date=["2015-10-17", "2015-10-19", "2015-10-20"];
var clicks=[5,3,1];

var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < all_date.length; i++)
{
  var indexInClickDate = click_date.indexOf(all_date[i]);
  if (indexInClickDate > -1)
    result.push(clicks[indexInClickDate]);
  else
    result.push(0);
}

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

However, `map()` function is more convenient to work with.